# Uploading a video to Gfycat using node.js returns `NotFoundo` from the Gfycat API

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, gfycat

I'm building a node app that uses [Gfycat's API](http://developers.gfycat.com/api/?curl#checking-the-status-of-your-upload) to upload a local MP4 to it and give me the URL of the converted gif. Here's what I have so far:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

async function main() {
  const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.gfycat.com/v1/gfycats",
    data: { title: "test" }
  });

  const name = res.data.gfyname;
  console.log(`The key name is: ${name}`)

  const stream = fs.createReadStream("./Video.mp4");
  const { size } = fs.statSync("./Video.mp4");

  stream.on("error", console.warn);

  const sendResult = await axios({
    method: "PUT",
    url: `https://filedrop.gfycat.com/${name}`,
    data: stream,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
      "Content-Length": size
    }
  });

  // Check the status of the encoding every n seconds until it says complete. When complete, return the gfyname.
  await waitTillPosted(name);

  return gfyname = checkResult.data.gfyname;
}

// Basic GET API request to check the encoding status of the gif
async function isPosted(name) {
  var checkResult = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://api.gfycat.com/v1/gfycats/fetch/status/${name}`,
  });
  console.log(`Current status: ${checkResult.data.task}`)

  if (checkResult.data.task == "complete") {
    return true;
  }
  throw new Error('The gif is still encoding.');
}

// Generic sleep function
function sleep(ms) {
  console.log(`Sleeping for ${ms} ms.`)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// If the gif is not done encoding, sleep 30s
async function waitTillPosted(name) {
  return isPosted(name).catch(() => sleep(30e3).then(waitTillPosted));
}

// ======================================================

main()
  .then(name => {
    console.log(`https://gfycat.com/${gfyname}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

According to the API, you can check the status of the conversion task with `GET https://api.gfycat.com/v1/gfycats/fetch/status/gfyname`.

When I run this app, the first `GET` request it makes reports `encoding`, as expected. I'm making a `GET` request every 30s until eventually, I expect it to say `complete`, where I'll return the Gfycat URL. However I'm get a `NotFoundo` instead.

I took one of the key names I got in my testing and checked the status with a `GET` request separately, and I got a proper `complete` response with the details of the gif. It works and the gif exists at the URL.

Why am I getting a `NotFoundo` when I do the same check as part of my main function?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug with gfycat. I often get it during rush-hours when I think their servers are overloaded.

My solution: Start all over a couple of times after waiting a short time-out. That's what "works" for me.

Also you may want to try a different video. Maybe they can't decode your file.